# Trying to get Data from the URL and get console warnings

Tags: ios, swift, ios12

I work in the Xcode 10 beta and iOS 12. Here is code snippet that appeared to be fine and do what it should do:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    guard let imageUrl = URL(string: course.imageUrl!) else { return }
    guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl) else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.courseImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
}
```

Next line:

```
guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl) else { return }
```

causes in simulator on iOS 12 next output in the console:

> 2018-09-07 12:02:25.045814+0500 Networking[69467:3561679] [BoringSSL]
> boringssl_session_errorlog(224) [C1.1:2][0x7fccdf534820]
> [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation failed within the
> library 2018-09-07 12:02:25.045951+0500 Networking[69467:3561679]
> [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(205)
> [C1.1:2][0x7fccdf534820] 140517895636904:error:100000d7:SSL
>
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSL_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl_Sim/boringssl-109.200.32/ssl/ssl_lib.cc:1081:
> 2018-09-07 12:02:25.046072+0500 Networking[69467:3561679] [BoringSSL]
> boringssl_session_errorlog(224) [C1.1:2][0x7fccdf534820]
> [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation failed within the
> library 2018-09-07 12:02:25.046208+0500 Networking[69467:3561679]
> [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(205)
> [C1.1:2][0x7fccdf534820] 140517895636904:error:100000d7:SSL
>
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSL_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl_Sim/boringssl-109.200.32/ssl/ssl_lib.cc:1081:
> 2018-09-07 12:02:25.049462+0500 Networking[69467:3561679] [BoringSSL]
> boringssl_session_errorlog(224) [C1.1:2][0x7fccdf534820]
> [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation failed within the
> library 2018-09-07 12:02:25.049585+0500 Networking[69467:3561679]
> [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(205)
> [C1.1:2][0x7fccdf534820] 140517895636904:error:100000d7:SSL
>
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSL_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl_Sim/boringssl-109.200.32/ssl/ssl_lib.cc:1081:
> 2018-09-07 12:02:25.049732+0500 Networking[69467:3561679] [BoringSSL]
> boringssl_session_errorlog(224) [C1.1:2][0x7fccdf534820]
> [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation failed within the
> library 2018-09-07 12:02:25.049998+0500 Networking[69467:3561679]
> [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(205)
> [C1.1:2][0x7fccdf534820] 140517895636904:error:100000d7:SSL
>
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSL_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl_Sim/boringssl-109.200.32/ssl/ssl_lib.cc:1081:

If I run iOS 11.4 simulator so message in the console will be other one and it appears after around 10-15 seconds:

> [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2881
> [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed
> because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert

Why this messages are in the console if I'am just trying as usual to get Data from the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appeared to be just console trash that was removed by:

[image]

Hope that will help someone.

Comment: Be aware this turns of a lot more logging than just `boringssl...` You may miss error messages you need to see.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t worry, it’s not your fault. It’s OS logging and fortunately, you can turn it off.

Open Product ▶️ Scheme ▶️ Edit Scheme …
Select Run
On Environment Variables, add OS_ACTIVITY_MODE with value disable

Comment: So I did it :) see my answer

Comment: Yes, I have seen your answer after commented.